# Erro para fazer requisição em Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

Estou enviando um request por ajax para meu servidor REST e estou recebendo de volta:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Junto com:

OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Alguem pode me dar uma luz de como resolver? Eu entendo que o problema provavelmente é no header de origem (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) mas não sei como passa-lo ou se o problema esta no client side ou server side.

Meu ajax está assim:

```
$(document).on('click', "#modalgravar", function(){


        var Ecdgrupo = $("#Cdgrupoedit").val();
        var Egrupo = $("#grupoedit").val();
        var eData = {"Cdgrupo": Ecdgrupo, "Grupos": Egrupo};
        var eURL = "http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/"


    alert(JSON.stringify(eData));

        $.ajax({
        type:"PUT",
        url: eURL,
        crossDomain : true,
        data: JSON.stringify(eData),
        contentType:"application/json",
         headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},


                success: function(){
                    alert("Editado!");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("ERRO:  O grupo não foi editado!");
                 },

              });   
           });
```

Quando tento realizar a chamada no Internet Explorer ele funciona perfeitamente, assim como usando o Postman. Mas no chrome e firefox ele me da esses erros.

Comment: Qual a linguagem do backend cara ? php, c#, nodejs ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro **especificamente** quando contêm `null`:

> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Indica que você esta tentando acessar via protocolo `file://` provavelmente (definitivamente?!), logo para isto ser permitido (se é que esta a intenção) o `crossDomain:true` não vai funcionar, isto tem que ser resolvido no back-end do seu "REST", até dá para resolver algumas situações no HTML mesmo, mas nem vou entrar nestes detalhes.

Já o erro 500 (Internal Server Error) indica erro no lado do servidor, não é no teu Ajax, isso porque quando o dominio de origem é diferente do dominio acessado no Ajax ele vai tentar acessar a URL via `OPTIONS` para verificar se existe as configurações para o CROSS-ORIGIN (CORS), se tiver configurado em seu back-end a rota com options e liberado com os headers (obviamente não precisa de todas, somente das que precisará enviar na requisição HTTP):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
Access-Control-Max-Age
```

Mas como no seu back-end/rest não deve nem existir isso, a tua aplicação BACK-END emite erro, pois a rota com OPTIONS não é configurada, ou esta mal configurada, ou tem algum erro no script, por ser qualquer coisa, claramente tudo isso é devido **erro de uso seu**

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Guilherme! Eu ainda sou iniciante então deixa eu ver se entendi algumas colocações: Quando vc diz protocolo file:// está se referindo ao caminho do HTML que eu estou usando no caso? Se for isso então de fato está assim mas não é definitivo, apenas para teste e desenvolvimento basico. O servidor REST não fui eu que criei, me foi cedido pronto para ser usado conforme o que estou desenvolvendo, porém vou verificar nele a questão dos Headers.

Comment: Caro @GabrielMidão então tem que entrar em contato com quem fez ele para modificar, me parece que funciona em localhost, signifca provavelmente que o outro desenvolvedor trabalha contigo, ou é parceria, se for o caso ele é quem poderá resolver, se ele entender de CORs é claro. Infelizmente é complicado resolver no front-end, já que `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` deve ser usado do lado do servidor não no Ajax. Creio que não podemos ajudar mais que isso, mas espero que as explicações ajudem a orientar sua equipe de trabalho. Até breve.

Comment: Me ajudou bastante, agora sei o caminho para corrigir. Obrigado novamente Guilherme!